# Server side paging with MVCContrib grid

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, mvccontrib, mvccontrib-grid

I have to use stored procedures to fetch and page data. This particular stored procedure has all sorts of parameters, including paging information. Obviously, paging needs to be done  server side, one page of data needs to be fetched each time a user selects a new page.

I'm trying to get this work with MVCContrib, but it seems to me that the grid and its pager support only local paging and filtering. Number of available pages is determined by the number of already present items in the collection, or so it seems to me.

Is there a way to make MVCContrib work with server side paging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to implement the IPagination interface yourself, add a page parameter to your action method then pass this into your stored procedure to get the appropriate collection of items. Then populate each of the IPagination properties from this and your knowledge of how your stored procedure works.

If you want more concrete examples of this, a sample of your stored procedure (or cut down version of it) may be helpful.

> "Number of available pages is determined by the number of already
>   present items in the collection, or so it seems to me."

Perhaps you're looking at samples that are using a flavour of LINQ. This does not necessarily mean that the entire collection is in memory. Also, even if they are in memory, I would still call this server side paging - To me, client side paging in a web application means javascript.

PS: this may help you get started, though by the sounds of it you will need to ignore the Entity Framework bits of it:

http://weblogs.asp.net/rajbk/archive/2010/05/08/asp-net-mvc-paging-sorting-filtering-using-the-mvccontrib-grid-and-pager.aspx

Where they use the "AsPagination()" extension you'll need to call your stored procedure and populate your own implementation of IPagination.

Answer (score 3):

There is a class called `CustomPagination` in MVCContrib. The constructor takes following arguments

```
(Enumerable<T> dataSource, int pageNumber, int pageSize, int totalItems)
```

Then you pass that to the Grid and Pager.